# convert external javascript to inline html (cargo)

Tags: javascript, html, inline, external

I'm new (like brand new) to Javascript and had some help in developing a code that would essentially 'erase' a class within an  tag on mouseover. I'm currently referencing it externally with `<script defer src= "./script.js">`. I'm trying to implement this accessorily in Cargo Collective which, by everything I'm reading, I'll have to use inline scripts for that. I have no clue even where to start, but I'm sure this is a common problem people on the site encounter. Here's all of the Javascript I'm using:

```
console.log('hello world!!')
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('g')
console.log(elements)

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
        event.target.setAttribute('class', 'hide')
    })
}
```

Comment: `event` must be declared as parameter in your function e.g. `function(event) {event.target.setAttribute('class', 'hide') }`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, run the snippet below, and see the adjustments I've made.

```js
//get an array of all elements with id="g"
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#g')

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
    //on mouseover remove className
        this.className = ""
    })
}
```

```css
.someClass {
background: blue;
color: yellow;
}

.someClass2 {
background: yellow;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover the divs below to remove their CSS class:</p>
<div id="g" class="someClass">im the g div</div>
<br>
<div id="g" class="someClass2">im the other g div</div>
```

If your code is in a file named `script.js` and is located in the root of where your HTML is located, then simply call that script like this right before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script defer src= "./script.js">
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to go completely inline you can call the whole function in your HTML document like this:

```
<script>
//get an array of all elements with id="g"
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#g')

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
    //on mouseover remove className
        this.className = ""
    })
}
</script>
```

Still, ensure you place the script before the closing `</body>` tag so the DOM is completely loaded before your function runs.